# Kendo grid: how to remove columns, fill new and refresh?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, calculated-columns

I have the Kendo grid which is filled by few columns. I would like to after button click update visibility some of these columns, add some new and push it back to display new columns.

I tried to do by this way:

```
// GET COLUMNS FROM GRID
var actualGridColumns = grid.columns; 
// MAKE SOME CHANGES LIKE hidden true/false on columns in loop
for loop
// SET NEW COLUMNS TO GRID
$("#orders_grid").data('kendoGrid').fields(actualGridColumns);
// FILL BY THE FRESH DATA FROM SERVER
$("#orders_grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
// REFRESH GRID
$("#orders_grid").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

But following code crashes on:

```
$("#orders_grid").data('kendoGrid').fields(actualGridColumns);
```

How can i do it in the right way please?

Comment: Could just not define any columns...? the grid will render whatever you have in your view() method of the data source... Just pump new data to the data source... the grid will adapt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `fields` method for grid.. To handle show/hide column, kendo provide method `showColumn` and `hideColumn`, you should check [Kendo Grid API Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid)

----------------------------EDIT------------------------------

Regarding to your case having new columns with new dataset you should re-define the entire grid column schema.
I make a simple [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EdOVE), you could develop it more complex to meet your expectation.
And here is kendo grid columns [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns) to help you define your column schema properly.

Hope this helps

Comment: show/hide Column is not suitable for me! I have whole new dataset with some new columns and i need to set this dataset of columns as new dataset. I tried to find something useful in Documentation, but without luck.

Comment: then you need to re-define the whole grid, because kendo doesn't support change on column definition on the fly

Comment: Could You post example? I hope that in this case is sufficient redefine grid config and columns, not pagination, read,delete requests, etc.. (because it is already availbale in global variable)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such **fields** method part of the Grid. You have two options:

- First is to define all the columns that you need at initialization time and just make some of them [hidden](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.hidden) and later on [show/hide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-showColumn) some of them based on your requirements.
- Another option is if you do not know the columns at the time of initialization, you can provide new set of columns options and pass them to the [setOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method of the Grid.